# expanding() function very slow, any alternatives?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compute cumulative standard deviation. I am using the following code

```
df['cum_std'] = df[df['growth'].notnull()].groupby('id')['growth'].expanding(2).std(ddof=0)
```

BUT, I have more than 90M rows of observation and it is taking forever. I am wondering if there are any other alternatives to do this faster?

for my current df

```
id  year    growth  many other variables...
A   2015     NaN    
A   2016    20000   
A   2017    19950
A   2018    30000   
A   2019    30050   
B   2015    NaN   
B   2016    2356    
B   2017    2446    
B   2018    3000    
B   2019    4560
```

desired df:

```
id  year    growth  cum_std
A   2015     NaN    NaN
A   2016    20000   0
A   2017    19950   25.00
A   2018    30000   4725.87
A   2019    30050   5025.06
B   2015    NaN     NaN
B   2016    2356    0
B   2017    2446    45.00
B   2018    3000    284.75
B   2019    4560    883.53
```

If there alternatives to this method so that I don't have to wait more than an hr for this line to be executed? Thanks!

Comment: Why is the std of a single number nan with ddof=0?

Comment: see the edited. I have not been able to apply the code, the above example is from excel.

Comment: I'm suggesting that `expanding(1)` is a more appropriate choice.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I can't use `expanding` bc it is too slow. I realized with a single number std will be 0. I am looking for alternatives to compute cummulative std.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `expanding` is computing the std over each window independently rather than using a cumulative operation that builds on prior steps. You can bypass that by implementing your own running standard deviation.

One way to define standard deviation of array `x` with `ddof=0` is `np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2 / N) - np.sum(x / N)**2)`. If you replace each `sum` with `cumsum`, you will get a running standard deviation. There will be numerical stability issues since `x**2` will likely blow up over 90M rows, even when you divide out `N`.

On mobile, so can't test, but you might try as follows:

```
g = df.groupby('id')
result = ((g**2 / g.cumcount()).cumsum() - (g / g.cumcount()).cumsum()**2).sqrt()
```

Comment: what is N here? Why would I need that if I just need to compute std for each id? my time window is at max 26 quarters and min 1 quarter (unbalanced panel). and your codes does not include the column "growth"? I have many variables in my df so I need to specify which column I am working with.

Comment: @Olive. N is the count up to that point.

Comment: @Olive. Turns out there's a way to do it.  I updated the answer

Comment: i get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'int'`

Comment: pls note i have many other variables, so instead of `g = df.groupby('id')`, i did `g = df.groupby('id')['growth']`

Comment: @Olive. My goal was to show you the way. Based on the fact that you've been able to adapt it to your exact needs, I'd say it was successful.